# Is it possible to define a 'global' getter/setter method on a Javascript object, so that it is invoked whenever any property is got/set?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have an Object:

```
const obj = {
  foo: bar,
  boop: "beep",
}
```

Now I would like to add some functionality that occurs **any** time a property is set (also get for this matter actually) in this object. Let's just keep it simple and say the added functionality is just a `console.log("a set/get action was just triggered on obj!")`.

How can I achieve this?

**Advanced extension:**

Naming the the **property** that was set and the **value** it was set with.

some sample behavior for clarity:

```
// simple:
obj.foo = "not bar anymore!";
// console output: a set/get action was just triggered on obj!

obj.rand = "a randomly added prop here";
// console output: a set/get action was just triggered on obj!


// advanced:
obj.boop = "burp";
// console output: a set/get action was just trigged on obj with prop: "boop", value: "burp".
obj.newRand = "a new randomly added prop here";
// console output: a set/get action was just trigged on obj with prop: "newRand", value: "a new randomly added prop here";
```

**Bonus:**

Any other ways to solve this issue are welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object with getter/setter traps instead.

The traps in the Proxy object allow you to interject the object methods with your custom functionality while returning the actual object data in the end of the process.

**Code example:**

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'bar',
  boop: "beep",
};
const objProx = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(obj, prop) {
    console.log('On obj', obj, 'getting', prop);
    return obj[prop];
  },
  set(obj, prop, newVal) {
    console.log('On obj', obj, 'setting', prop, 'to', newVal);
    return obj[prop] = newVal;
  },
});

objProx.boop = "burp";
objProx.newRand = "a new randomly added prop here";
// invokes getter:
objProx.foo;
```

Comment: I believe this is the best approach considering that getters and setters have almost no compatibility on modern browsers (in ES5 at least)

Comment: Nice, so the Proxy is like some sort of middleware

Comment: *"proxy - The agency, function, or power of a person authorized to act as the deputy or substitute for another."* - [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/proxy) So you could say some sort of middleware, but more specific.

Comment: Yeah I was just used to express middleware :-), but it would be better to call middlewares a from of proxy.